# Работа с api openweathermap

Tags: python, openweathermap

Всем привет. Когда изучал python я решил попробовать сделать программу для отображения погоды и температуры.
Сам код -

```
import requests

url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=moscow&type=like&APPID=03d92e1dcdf06982a35783083f52690a'
res = requests.get(url)
data = res.json()

print(data)
weather = data['main'][0]['description']
temp = data['main']['temp']
desp = data['weather'] [0] ['description']
print(weather)
print(temp)
```

Но этот код выдаёт следующую ошибку -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anatolyo\Desktop\asf.py", line 8, in <module>
    weather = data['main'][0]['description']
KeyError: 'main'
```

Прошу помочь с данной ошибкой, api ключ правильный 100% .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

def kelToCel(fah):
    cel = fah - 273.15
    return round(cel)
    
def getWeather():
    weatherInfo = {}
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=moscow&type=like&APPID=03d92e1dcdf06982a35783083f52690a'
    res = requests.get(url)
    data = res.json()
    
    weatherInfo['temp'] = kelToCel(data['list'][0]['main']['temp'])
    weatherInfo['desc'] = data['list'][0]['weather'][0]['description']
    
    return weatherInfo


print(getWeather())
```